# SapUI5 - How can i bind an object Master-Detail page?

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to bind and present an element to a detail page, but no success about it.

the master page is displayed well and present the data.
but when i want to present the item on a detail page the data doesn't displayed.
*for fetching all the data i use an API request

I'm not sure what am i doing wrong.

Heres the code:

**Controller.Overview.js**

```
            var data =  {id: 19265, typeId: 5, foreignKeyId: 1, foreignKeyTextId: "316e2c71-d1d1-f73c-4696-70912d6cf240", value: 0, Name: "jim"}
                        ,{id: 19268, typeId: 5, foreignKeyId: 1, foreignKeyTextId: "316e2c71-d1d1-f73c-4696-70912d6cf240", value: 0, Name: "john"}

            var newArr2 = {"Overview" : data};
                        oModel.setData(newArr2);
                        oView.setModel(oModel);

            onListItemPressed : function(oEvent){
                var oItem, oCtx;

                oItem = oEvent.getSource();
                oCtx = oItem.getBindingContext();

                this.getRouter().navTo("overviewItem",{
                    OverviewId : oCtx.getProperty("OverviewId")
                });

            }
```

**Overview.xml**

```
       <List id="dataJS" headerText="dataJS" items="{/Overview}">
            <items>
                <StandardListItem
                    title="{foreignKeyTextId}"
                    iconDensityAware="false"
                    iconInset="false"
                    type="Navigation"
                    press="onListItemPressed"/>
            </items>
        </List>
```

**controller.Overviewitem.js**

```
            return BaseController.extend("com.sap.it.cs.itsupportportaladmin.controller.feedbackanalytics.OverviewItem", {

                    _formFragments: {},

                    onInit: function () {
                        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
                        oRouter.getRoute("overviewItem").attachMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
                    },

                    _onRouteMatched : function (oEvent) {
                        var oArgs, oView;
                        oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");
                        oView = this.getView();

                        oView.bindElement({
                            path : "/Overview(" + oArgs.OverviewId + ")",
                            events : {
                                change: this._onBindingChange.bind(this),
                                dataRequested: function (oEvent) {
                                    oView.setBusy(true);
                                },
                                dataReceived: function (oEvent) {
                                    oView.setBusy(false);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    },

                    _onBindingChange : function (oEvent) {
                        // No data for the binding
                        if (!this.getView().getBindingContext()) {
                            this.getRouter().getTargets().display("notFound");
                        }
                    }

                });
```

**OverviewItem.xml**

```
            <mvc:View
                controllerName="com.sap.it.cs.itsupportportaladmin.controller.feedbackanalytics.OverviewItem"
                xmlns="sap.m"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
                xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
                busyIndicatorDelay="0">
                <Page
                    id="overviewPage"
                    title="{Name}"
                    showNavButton="true"
                    navButtonPress="onNavBack"
                    class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
                    <content>
                        <Panel
                            id="employeePanel"
                            width="auto"
                            class="sapUiResponsiveMargin sapUiNoContentPadding">
                            <headerToolbar>
                                <Toolbar>
                                    <Title text="{OverviewId}" level="H2"/>
                                    <ToolbarSpacer />
                                    <Link text="{i18n>FlipToResume}" tooltip="{i18n>FlipToResume.tooltip}" press="onShowResume" />
                                </Toolbar>
                            </headerToolbar>
                        </Panel>
                    </content>
                </Page>
            </mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. `/Overview(" + oArgs.OverviewId + ")"` will not work as your model an array and not object as per code in Controller.Overview.js:

   ```
       var data =  {id: 19265, typeId: 5, foreignKeyId: 1, foreignKeyTextId: "316e2c71-d1d1-f73c-4696-70912d6cf240", value: 0, Name: "jim"}
                   ,{id: 19268, typeId: 5, foreignKeyId: 1, foreignKeyTextId: "316e2c71-d1d1-f73c-4696-70912d6cf240", value: 0, Name: "john"}

       var newArr2 = {"Overview" : data};
                   oModel.setData(newArr2);
                   // this resolves to :
                   newArr2 = {"Overview" : [ {id: 19265...}, {id: 19268...} ]}
                   oView.setModel(oModel);
   ```

You will have to find index of Clicked item and do :
`/Overview/" + oArgs.OverviewIndex` resulting in somethin like: `Overview/0` or `Overview/1` etc.

2. Also, you have set the model only to your master list.

`oView.setModel(oModel);` where oView is in Controller.Overview.js.

Please set the model to your complete split-app for binding context to work correctly.

===========

Update after Discussion: Store you data as an Object:

```
// id as the key. SO, you can easily fetch person.
var data = {
        "19265" : {id: 19265, typeId: 5, foreignKeyId: 1, foreignKeyTextId: "316e2c71-d1d1-f73c-4696-70912d6cf240", value: 0, Name: "jim"},
        "19268" : {id: 19268, typeId: 5, foreignKeyId: 1, foreignKeyTextId: "316e2c71-d1d1-f73c-4696-70912d6cf240", value: 0, Name: "john"}
    };
```

And Set binding on click as:

```
 oView.bindElement({
                        path : "/Overview/" + oArgs.OverviewId + "",
                        events : {
                            change: this._onBindingChange.bind(this),
                            dataRequested: function (oEvent) {
                                oView.setBusy(true);
                            }, ... rest of code.
```

Comment: OK. but how can i save the data not in an ARRAY format? and also, the master page is also a child page of the main page, so i think i need to load the data only on the master page, not?

Comment: @Eli: Added info